Does Ibn Abbas believe sunset in murky spring is literally
in this Hadith it states
Muhammad b. Abd al-A’la Al-San’ani Al-Basri (d.245) <– Marwan b. Muawiyah b. Al-Harith Al-Kufi (d.193) <– Warqa b. Umar b. Qulayb Al-Kufi (d.160) <– Sayd b. Jubayr Al-Kufi (45-95): ibn Abbas read this letter {In a muddy spring} and he said: Black mud that the sun sets in.
This basically says that the sun literally sets in the black mud if this is true then it would be unscientific was Ibn Abbas the best of all tafseer and interpretation of the Quran.

Hope that at least one of the mods would answer I actually want to know @Medi1Saif

Even if this is true, there's no problem with it. Ibn Abbas radiallahu'anhu lived about 1400 years ago, and you expect him to know about modern scientific discoveries somehow? Even if he somehow did, everyone can make mistakes.

When we say the best mufassir, we don't mean infallible by any means or having knowledge about all the laws of the universe. Different scholars use different academic criteria to determine the greatness of a tafsir work, and I am sure none of them ever included "Author expresses knowledge of all the laws of physics, astronomy, and the universe" .

Okay then a second question is it possible for Ibn Abbas tafsir to be wrong even though the Hadith says he well have the right interpretation are there scholars who said he could be wrong and what were there reasons.@SyedM.Sannan

Yes, It can be wrong. There is no infallable personality, and I mean absolutely none except the Prophets, peace be upon them, Aameen. The burden of proof is upon you to prove that Islam says he was infallible. If he really was considered as such, then no other tafasir would be written after him and everyone would just accept his tafsir as the de facto truth. There is no such idea. He is simply the best of the mufassireen but by no means infallible.

I want to make it clear that am a Muslim here and am no were trying to insult am not even saying he has a infallabe personality am justing saying that in Musnad Aḥmad 2879 it says that Muhammad (pbuh) prayed that allah will teach him the correct interpation of the Quran all am asking is for scholars who say that Ibn Abbas can make mistake in his interpation of the Quran that all and Salam

Dear, I never said you are trying to insult. The main point is that no one is infallible in Islam unless proven otherwise. And the only people proven to be infallible are Prophets, peace be upon them. That's the basic principle. So can you please tell me a list of scholars who say he was infallible? If you can't, and I am sure you can't as no scholar ever said that, then he isn't infallible. What you mentioned was simply a dua made by the Prophet PBUH for Ibn Abbas and a more just translation of it would be:

"O Allah, give him understanding in religion and teach him the interpretation of the Quran.", this is the most common English translation of it. Now tell me how it even implies that he radiallahu'anhu was infallible.

Sorry for the late response but many scholars have indicated that this mean the exact right interpretation of the Quran was meant by this Hadith this means that his interpretation of his tafsir has to be infallible all I am asking ounce again is a scholar who says that ibn abbas could get it wrong in tafsir just name one

You first name one who says that his tafsir is infallible, just one. Because no text or person is infallible in Islam until proven otherwise. Secondly, if his tafsir was considered truly infallible, then considering usul, it would actually be haram to write more tafsir later on. You think all the scholars that wrote tafasir after him would commit haram intentionally? In Islam, if something is considered infallible, then it is haram to make something compared to it or to even add upon it more content.

Not a single scholar in history, I guarantee you, considers his tafsir infallible. None. Absolutely none.
